# How to chose minimum and target versions of Windows 10 SDK

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

There are several Windows UWP SDKs available [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive). I want to start developing a UWP app and its bit confusing for me to chose an SDK version.
If I use an SDK like **Windows 10 SDK (10586)** does that mean my app only works with Windows 10 OS build 10586 and above? and will not works with Windows 10 OS build 10240?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you install the Windows 10 SDK version 10586 you will be able to add all features to your application that are included till that release of the SDK including all the previous features.

On creating a new UWP project you will be asked for the targeted and minimum version of Windows 10 that you application is supported on as well as the targeted version(as shown below) :

[image]

In this image you can see that the target version for the application is 14393 but the minimum is 10586, thus the application will work on all versions of windows greater than or equal to 10586.

> Thus it depends on which version of windows you select when creating a
>   project .  Having a SDK version greater than what you are targeting will **not** restrict you from developing application for lower versions , but the newly introduced features which are specific to the new version will not be available in the application if it is targeted for lower versions of windows.

More info : [Choose a UWP version (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So if I set my min version to 10240 and target version to be Build 15063 (Creators Update) and add a feature introduced on 15063 to my app. Will that work on 10240?

Comment: You can add the feature that is introduced in 15063 in your application and it will be available only on the supported windows 10 versions,but your application will continue working in all versions greater than 10240(minimum version)..