# CMake targeting from a minimum Windows SDK version and above

Tags: windows, cmake, sdk

VS Studio has the ability to set a minimum windows SDK version and a target SDK version. See:

[How to chose minimum and target versions of Windows 10 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45541377/how-to-chose-minimum-and-target-versions-of-windows-10-sdk)

I'm developing using CMake and Ninja so I don't use VS Studio directly. My question is related to CMake usage of a minimum and target SDK version for Windows.

You can set CMake variable `CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION` to set a target SDK version. But which is the behavior? Does this target version is the current SDK version or is the minimum SDK version?

My goal is to create an app targeting from a specific minimum windows SDK version onwards, say Windows 10.0.18362 and above.
My understanding is `CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION` works like a sort of minimum version... but not sure.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is [the `VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_MIN_VERSION` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_MIN_VERSION.html).

Some info I found about the difference between target version and minimum target version is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/general-property-page-project#target-platform-min-version):

> [The minimum] Specifies the lowest version of the platform that the project can run on. This property appears only if the project type supports it. Set this value if your app can take advantage of features in a newer Windows SDK version, but still runs on earlier versions, perhaps with some loss of functionality. If set to a lower value, your code should check the version of the platform it's running against at runtime. Then, disable features that aren't available in older platform versions.

I have no idea how this is related to [`TargetDeviceFamily`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-targetdevicefamily), which it seems like CMake hard-codes to `<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0"/>` (see `Source/cmVisualStudio10TargetGenerator.cxx`).

Comment: Actually I've already looked into that. The problem is I'm using ninja, thus I don't create a VS Studio build at all. Otherwise that would apply. There must be some form of conversione between the two, but I have probably to look inside VS Studio configuration files for cmake...

Comment: @kabq d'oh. I didn't read your question carefully. sorry about that.